# How to keep the scroll at top when the routing happens in remix?

Tags: remix.run

When I move from one page to another using the Link component in remix i want the scroll to be at the top. Currently when i move from one route to another say from `/` to `/products`, the scroll position from `/` is maintained in `/products` too.

what i want is `/products`'s scroll position should be on top when clicked on link
currently i am using `<Link/>` from remix, but its giving the above problem.

I have tried removing `<ScrollRestoration />` component and the `preventScrollReset  = {false}` for `Link` but nothing seems to work.

in root.tsx after removing the `<ScrollRestoration />`

```
<body>
 <Nav />
 <Outlet />
 <Scripts />
 <LiveReload />
 <Footer  />
</body>
```

how to fix this ? please refer me some projects/solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide a simple repo? I'm not experiencing that issue.

Here's an example that shows how navigating from page to page will always scroll to the top, and going back will restore the previous scroll position.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/remix-run-remix-yygbnk?file=app%2Froutes%2Fscroll.%24page.tsx

Comment: Hey @Kiliman does the context of where my Link element is placed affects the scroll restoration? Because i am using the `Nav, Foooter` component which contains all the links my website needs

Comment: It shouldn't. Can you update the stack blitz to show the problem you're having?

Answer (score 0):

I even tried of using the approach of window.scrollTo() but it doesn't preserve the scroll position of the last page, instead it scrolls to top whenever the pathname changes.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ScrollToTop() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
}
```

Import this component in root.tsx or the layout

```
  <body>
    <Nav />
    <Outlet />
    <ScrollToTop/>
    <ScrollRestoration/>
    <Scripts />
    <LiveReload />
    <Footer  />
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick reminder that The  Doesn't work if there is a css property named `overflow-x: auto;` applied on Parent (usually `html` or `body` tags) this was the real culprit In my case.